# IIS Windows authentication doesn't works after SSL Binding

Tags: ssl, http-error-401.2

Hi I have an IIS Web Site, on W2019 server, with Windows authentication enabled. With the http binding the windows authentication works fine. With the https binding I have a loop of the login prompt and I'm not able to logon. If i click on the cancel button of the the login prompt, i get "401.2 - Unauthorized. You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers. Error Code     0x80070005"
The certificate was installed fine (I think): if I disable the Windows Authentication and I use basic authentication (or anonymous) the web site is showed fine both with http and https binding. Host name are specified both on IIS bindings and on DNS as new A host name.

I've googled all the day without success. Any idea to solve the issue? I need to use the Windows Authentication :-(. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

solved by using Negotiate instead of ntlm authentication and by execute setspn commands.